# asp.net MVC3 View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to open  a view that says update or insert successful. I did not create an action because I only want a simply status page.  I created a view called Status.cshtml
I get a message saying that the view cannot be found. Any idea what is wrong?
Do I need an action for this to work?

Comment: 1: Please accept answers for your past questions. 2: Please provide enough code to give us an idea of how you're trying to invoke the view now.

Comment: Can you provide code from your controller?

Comment: possible duplicate of [asp.net mvc utilize view for rendering, without creating a controller action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056308/asp-net-mvc-utilize-view-for-rendering-without-creating-a-controller-action)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a View is not enough. Your request first reaches a controller action through Asp.net mvc routing and only if the correct action is found the relevant view is displayed. [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-UdqWy9lVc) is a video if you need a quick grab of how asp.net controllers and views work.

Answer (score 4):

When your process has finished successfully use the following line of code...

`return View("Status");`

Note: There is no action method with the same name - so navigating to *www.yourdomain.com/YourController/Status* will not route correctly...