# ASP.NET MVC: RenderActionToString

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need an Html Helper that renders an action to as a string. Anyone know of any?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string/484932#484932

Comment: I want to render a View via an Action method, not render a View directly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to render the related View also? [Maybe this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string) will get you started. Or if you intended to return a string from an Action, [check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520863/send-asp-net-mvc-action-result-inside-email).

Comment: What I really need to do is somehow execute an Action method (ie: GetProductByID()) from a Controller that uses its repository to get the name of the product. I know this violates the philosophy of MVC by having a view depend on application logic but for my special case, this approach would make my life easier.