# Get the result HTML from ViewResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewresult

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Send asp.net mvc action result inside email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520863/send-asp-net-mvc-action-result-inside-email)
>   [Render a view as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string)

I would like to obtain the result HTML from one of my controller actions, and simply send the result as a HTML format email. However, I am having difficulties trying to figure out how to obtain that HTML from ViewResult.

One approach I have tried is to implement HtmlEmailActionFilter that inherits from ActionFilterAttribute. But I still don't know how to get the HTML from ResultExecutedContext.

Am I on the right track? If not, what would be a better way to perform what I would like to accomplish?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520863/send-asp-net-mvc-action-result-inside-email/

Comment: actually, i don't think it is a duplicate. the OP is looking for a way to achieve this in an actionfilter, rather than in the action. i was just about to post the solution when the post was closed :)

Comment: @jim - I would love to see your solution. Is there a way to have this reopen so you can post your answer?

Comment: @jimtollan I'd really like to see your solution too. People are really heavy-handed with closing questions. I guess because you can get easy points.

Comment: Ev - was way back *when*, but will see if I can recall what I was on the verge of answering, when the heavy hands dropped!! :-)